# Using Vulkan with Code::Blocks on Windows 10

Tags: windows, code-blocks

I'm new to Vulkan and APIs in general so I'm wondering how I can get Vulkan to work on Code::Blocks. I've seen many tutorials but they were all about Visual Studio. I have tried doing the same on Code::Blocks but there were missing functionalities and it's just different. To be honest, I really didn't much time trying to figure out how on my own but I hope you can still answer.

Thank  you very much.